# Trying to join tables in laravel without join elqouent query

Tags: php, html, laravel, encoding

here is the code That joins two tables users(id,last_name,firstname) barbers(id,id_user) avis(id,rating,id_user) now my problem is that i'm trying to join between tables without using join I want another way

```
 $users = User::select('barbers.*','users.*')
            ->join('barbers', 'barbers.id_user', '=', 'users.id')
            ->join('avis','avis.id_barber','=','barbers.id')
            ->whereHas('commandes', function ($query) use ($searchTermes1) {
                $query->where('barbers.id', '>', 0)
                      ->havingRaw('count(*) >= ?', [(int)$searchTermes1]);
            })
            ->whereIn('barbers.id_state', [1, 4])
            ->where('isValidate', true)
            
                                 ->where(function ($query) use ($searchTerm) {
                $query->where('barbers.name_barber', 'like', '%'.$searchTerm.'%')
                      ->orWhereRaw("concat(first_name, ' ', last_name) like '%$searchTerm%'")
                      ->orWhereRaw("concat(last_name, ' ', first_name) like '%$searchTerm%'");
            })
            
            ->orderBy('barbers.created_at', 'desc')
            
            ->paginate(10);
```

Comment: try using relationship, declare it inside your model , see documentation for more info https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a Laravel guy, but it looks from a little searching like you could do something like this:

```
Model::select(DB::raw('your-raw-join-query-here'))->get();
```

That would allow you to run raw SQL directly, if you really need to. Hopefully someone else will have a more elegant answer.